# Python / Flask - Internal Server Error on hosting server

Tags: python, flask, internal-server-error

On the local server this Python app works perfectly, however, when I set up this Python app on my server where my site is hosted, `index.html` loads and that means Python is well set up, but when I click the `Transcribe button`, after as I `select the language` and `.wav file`, an error occurs:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

Does anyone have any idea where the error is here and if it is not an error, how to overcome the server response.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
import speech_recognition as sr
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

def get_languages():
    url = 'https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/languages'
    resp = requests.get(url)
    start_text = '        <tbody class="list">\n'
    end_text = '        </tbody>\n'
    table = resp.text.split(start_text)[1].split(end_text)[0]
    tr_start = '          <tr>\n'
    sections = table.split(tr_start)[1:]
    languages = []

    for section in sections:
        short = section.splitlines()[1].split('<td>')[1].split('<')[0]
        long = section.splitlines()[0].split('<td>')[1].split('<')[0]
        if len(languages) > 0:
            # dupe check. For some reason the page has all
            # languages twice
            if languages[-1] != {'short': short, 'long': long}:
                languages.append({'short': short, 'long': long})
        else:
            languages.append({'short': short, 'long': long})
    print(f'FOUND {len(languages)} LANGUAGES')
    return languages

language_list = get_languages()

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    transcript = ""
    if request.method == "POST":
        print("FORM DATA RECEIVED")
        # set the language, use en-US by default
        language = request.form.get('lang') or 'en-US'

        print(f'SELECTED LANGUAGE: {language}')

        if "file" not in request.files:
            return redirect(request.url)

        file = request.files["file"]
        if file.filename == "":
            return redirect(request.url)

        if file:
            recognizer = sr.Recognizer()
            audioFile = sr.AudioFile(file)

            with audioFile as source:
                data = recognizer.record(source)
                recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)

            # change the line below
            transcript = recognizer.recognize_google(data, language=language)
    
    return render_template('index.html', transcript=transcript, language_list=language_list)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, threaded=True)
```

log file

```
FOUND 137 LANGUAGES
FORM DATA RECEIVED
SELECTED LANGUAGE: en-US
FOUND 137 LANGUAGES
[2021-08-08 13:37:18,913] ERROR in app: Exception on / [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mysrv/virtualenv/transcriber/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2070, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/mysrv/virtualenv/transcriber/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1515, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/mysrv/virtualenv/transcriber/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1513, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/mysrv/virtualenv/transcriber/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1499, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "app.py", line 58, in index
    transcript = recognizer.recognize_google(data, language=language)
  File "/home/mysrv/virtualenv/transcriber/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 828, in recognize_google
    convert_width=2  # audio samples must be 16-bit
  File "/home/mysrv/virtualenv/transcriber/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 445, in get_flac_data
    flac_converter = get_flac_converter()
  File "/home/mysrv/virtualenv/transcriber/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 1183, in get_flac_converter
    flac_converter = shutil_which("flac")  # check for installed version first
  File "/home/mysrv/virtualenv/transcriber/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 1217, in shutil_which
    for p in path.split(os.path.pathsep):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: I recommend running it on the server using a terminal and then looking at the exception that is shown when the error occurs. How/Where are you running it on the server? Linux? Windows?

Comment: It's a leased hosting server, as far as I'm aware it's a Linux server, my access is limited, I run Python using the cPanel.

Comment: You need to access the log file. There you see what's the problem

Comment: I add the log file, please look.

Comment: Could you verify that the variable "language" has content? Just print it maybe.

Comment: It doesn't matter, the variable "language" is only used to print text in the language specified in the drop-down menu

Comment: I have the impression that the problem here is in the server response time, how can I try to overcome that problem?

Comment: do you have flac installed on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot comment in the above discussion due to less points.
No it is not due to server response time.

Did you try with
`transcript = recognizer.recognize_google(data)` instead

Comment: I've already tried to throw out `language=language` but it doesn't work, the same error appears.

Comment: form the log above
  ** File "app.py", line 58, in index
    transcript = recognizer.recognize_google(data, language=language) **
this is the problematic line.
can you just comment that so that we are sure there is no problem with the server response time ?

Comment: Yes, I noticed that too, but how to correct that line and overcome the problem?

Comment: When I commented on this line, the problem disappeared, which means that the problem is in the server response time, as I have already pointed out.

Comment: I think i cannot help much since i cannot access your system but there is tutorial pls check if it helps.

https://realpython.com/python-speech-recognition/

Comment: @Dejo Did this answer work ? i think you have tried this before ?

Comment: I was able to run the service on the provider's server by copying Flac as the Flac command: `cp /home/myusername/virtualenv/transcriber/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/speech_recognition/flac-linux-x86_64 /home/myusername/virtualenv/transcriber/3.7/bin/flac` but I'm very sorry that I can't rewrite longer audio files, I measured, the longest to which the server responds is 5MB or 3-5 minutes of speech to an audio file. Do you have any idea how to bridge this problem and have a server response time indefinitely?

Comment: Do you know how I can make the server read larger files without showing an error: Internal Server Error

Comment: So if I understand the requirement correctly,
The server should be able to read and send large files, probably in GB's.
and which server do you use to host your application ?

Comment: Yes, the server needs to read large files, maybe over 1GB, for hosting, as you can see from written, Linux is used, I asked a question in this post, please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68777686/how-to-perform-speech-recognition-on-large-audio-files-in-python